# Count the occurrence of a value in table in R

Tags: r

For the below data set, how can we count the occurrence of a value in the table?
For example, i want to count how many times U, X,Y,Z have occurred in below data set in single code.

Expected output wrt to below data set.

```
U    15 
X    08
Y    07
Z    03


h1   h2  h3  h4  h5  h6  h7  h8
U   U   NULL    U   Y   NULL    Y   X
U   NULL    U   U   Y   Y   X   X
U   U   U   NULL    U   NULL    Y   NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
X   V   U   U   Y   NULL    Z   X
Y   X   NULL        X   Y   Z   U
X   NULL    U   NULL    NULL    U   Z   Y
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Please be so kind to provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `df` is your dataframe. One simple way to count the number of occurrence is: `sum(df == X, na.rm = TRUE)`.

To get all the counts, one would need code like the following:

```
values <- c("U","V","X","Y","Z")
sapply(values,function(x,y){sum(y == x, na.rm = TRUE)},data )
```

and the output:

```
> sapply(values,function(x,y){sum(y == x, na.rm = TRUE)},data )
 U  V  X  Y  Z 
15  1  8  9  3 
>
```

Comment: This answer requires prior knowledge of all the values in the data frame in advance, becoming unwieldy as the number of values increases, because you'd need extra code to get all the counts for each distinct value in the data frame, per my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using `tidyr`, after adding a NULL to row 6 of the data since it only had 7 columns. Note that the raw data has 9 Ys, not 7 as summarized in the OP, as well as 1 V.

```
rawData <- "h1   h2  h3  h4  h5  h6  h7  h8
U   U   NULL    U   Y   NULL    Y   X
U   NULL    U   U   Y   Y   X   X
U   U   U   NULL    U   NULL    Y   NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
X   V   U   U   Y   NULL    Z   X
Y   X   NULL    NULL    X   Y   Z   U
X   NULL    U   NULL    NULL    U   Z   Y
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL"

data <- read.table(text=rawData,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                   header=TRUE,na.strings="NULL")
library(tidyr)
tidyData <- gather(data,key="variable",na.rm=TRUE)
table(tidyData$value)
```

...and the output:

```
> table(tidyData$value)

 U  V  X  Y  Z 
15  1  8  9  3 
>
```

Using `dplyr` along with `tidyr`, the solution looks like this.

```
library(dplyr)
gather(data,key="variable",na.rm=TRUE) %>% 
     group_by(value) %>% summarise(n= n())
```

...and the output:

```
> gather(data,key="variable",na.rm=TRUE) %>% 
+      group_by(value) %>% summarise(n= n())
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  value     n
  <chr> <int>
1 U        15
2 V         1
3 X         8
4 Y         9
5 Z         3
>
```